# What's the advantage of multimap over map of vectors?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, multimap

I don't understand why multimap exists if we can create map of vectors or map of sets.
For me only differences are:

- using `equal_range` in multimap for getting elements of a key and in map of vectors we simply use `[]` operator and have vector of elements.
- using `multimap.insert(make_pair(key,value))` in multimap for adding elements and `map_of_vectors[key].push_back(value)` in map of vectors.

So why use multimap? For me it's better to have a vector than two iterators to get all values of a key.

This question applies also to unordered_map of vectors and unordered_multimap.

Comment: I must admit I never quite understood the purpose of `multimap` :/

Comment: I little bit late in the question but also multimap consumes much more memory than map of vectors due the extra pointers. The only reason I'd use them is if I want to keep the key of each element (doing `push_back` you won't keep it)

Comment: Multimap is great if you not only want to keep track of duplicate keys of differing values, but you also want to delete any key/value pair at a moments notice. A map of vectors isn't suitable for that, and while you can use a map of lists, it's more convenient to just use a multimap.

Comment: While I see your point (and I also don't tend to use multimap), about the same thing can be said about `map<K, V>` vs. `set<pair<K, V>, cmp_first<K, V>>` where cmp_first compares the `.first` member.

Comment: map of sets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602068/whats-the-difference-between-stdmultimapkey-value-and-stdmapkey-stds

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆再教育营六四事件法轮功郝海东 what about 'em?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I would say it depends on whether all the values with same key have a relationship that you want to address.

So for example, do you often go through all elements with key X, or pass them to a function, and so on? Then it is more convenient to already have them in their separate container, that you can address directly.

However, if you just have a collection of items, that may share same key value, or not, why use vectors in between? It is more convenient to run through the multimap with iterators than have a nested for-loop for the map, vector case.

Another way of looking at this: If multiple entries per key is very common, your structure is more efficient in the map, vector case. If they seldomly happen, it is the opposite.

Comment: Thanks. Your and Artyom's answer showed me a little more differences. However I still don't believe multimap is as useful in real life as map of vectors. But that's my personal opinion ;)

Comment: My practical extract from this answer is: with `multimap` you can have iterator range covering the whole structure but such begin/end iterators will iterate pairs of key and value (which may not be convenient). With `map<...,vector>` iterating the whole structure is more complex, but you can have begin/end iterators of equal sequence of just values.

Answer (score 67):

There are many important differences between `multimap<x, y>` and `map<x, vector<y>>`

Once you had inserted a value into *multimap*, you know that the iterator would remain
valid until you remove it and this is very strong property, you can't have it with map of vectors.

```
multimap<x,y>::iterator p=mymap.insert(make_pair(a,b));
```

The iterator remains valid until it is erased from map, while in second case,
it would be invalidated each time you add new entry to the vector.

Also note that `map<x, vector<y>>` may have an empty value set with existing key, while multimap does not.

These are different things that behave differently.

And to be honest I miss multimap in some languages that do not provide it in their library.

Comment: While the angle of iterator-invalidation is interesting, your statement *"it would be invalidated **each** time you add new entry to the vector."* is not practically true. The iterator gets invalidated only when the vector resizes, else not... though since you don't usually know/care when it gets resized, we just shouldn't design our code around the resizing and simply *assume* iterators get invalidated on insertion!

Comment: @Nawaz consider inserting (adding new) and erasing