# Accessing elements in a mulimap

Tags: c++, c++11, iteration, key-value, multi-mapping

I am trying to create a program that takes in data from a .txt or similar file and asks the user for a word to search for. The output should show the keyword in context with the 2 words that were originally in front of it, as well as behind it. (EX: keyword: boy would output "and the boy ran away") I am able to find all instances of the keyword in the file with the equal_range() function, however I do not know how to iterate through the data in the map to access the other words for context. Here is my code so far:

```
typedef multimap<string, int> templateMap;
templateMap wordMap;
typedef pair<templateMap::iterator, templateMap::iterator> searchTemplate;
searchTemplate search;
typedef pair<templateMap::const_iterator, templateMap::const_iterator> innerIteratorTemplate;
multimap<string, int>::iterator tempMap;
string tempWord;
string keyword;

// omitted code

for (size_t i = 0; !inData.eof(); i++)  
{
    inData >> tempWord;
    wordMap.insert(pair<string, int>(tempWord, i));
}

search = wordMap.equal_range(keyword);

for (multimap<string, int>::iterator itr = search.first; itr != search.second; ++itr)
{
    cout << "The keyword " << keyword << " is found at location " << itr->second << endl;

    tempMap = itr;
    itr->second = itr->second - 2;
    cout << itr->first << endl;
}
```

I am aware that the code in the for loop at the bottom is wrong, but it was for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You need bidirectional lookup: you need to map a word to its index (this is what `wordMap` is for) and separately you need to map an index to its word (this is what you're missing). So let's add that, as well as fixing your initial loop:

```
std::vector<std::string> words;
while (inData >> tempWord) {
    wordMap.insert(std::make_pair(tempWord, words.size()));
    words.push_back(tempWord);
}
```

Now, we have it bidirectionally - since `words` allows lookup by index. Thus, we have:

```
for (auto const& pair : as_range(wordMap.equal_range(keyword))) {
    for (size_t idx = pair.second - 2; idx < pair.second + 3; ++idx) {
        std::cout << words[idx] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

`as_range()` is something that takes a pair of iterators and gives you back something you can use in a range-based for expression. This doesn't account for the bounds of `words` (if you pick one of the first two or last two words as your keyword), but this should put you on the right track.

---

Additionally, consider using `std::map<std::string, std::vector<size_t>>` instead of `std::multimap<std::string, size_t>` if you're always going to be iterating over all the values and don't need iterator stability. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4437862/2069064) for more info.

Comment: Is as_range something that needs to be included from something else other than algorithm, math, vector, and iostream? My compiler tells me it is undefined and I cannot find a clear answer anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Given your problem statement, a `map` is ill-suited since you immediately lose all positional information and you're left trying to find a workaround. If you are willing the hold all your data in a container, you may as well hold it in a `vector` and perform a linear search. Yes, I know, it will be *theoretically* slower but there's a fair chance it won't be in practice...

For giggles, here's a completely different approach with `<regex>` facilities:

```
// Data.
string const text = "Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The five boxing wizards jump quickly.";

// Word to search for.
string target;
cin >> target;

// Capture the target and up to two words before and after.
regex const context(R"((?:([^\s]+)\s)?(?:([^\s]+)\s)?()" + target + R"()(?:\s([^\s]+))?(?:\s([^\s]+))?)");

// Perform search.
smatch matches;
regex_search(text, matches, context);

// Print results.
copy_if(matches.begin() + 1, matches.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"), mem_fn(&smatch::value_type::matched));
```